# ExpressionEngine 'loop'

Tags: channel-entries

I have a page in a website created with expressionengine. In my site, posts are shown with exerpt and by clicking the 'readmore" using  {title_permalink=''} you go to a 'single-post' page. On that template that is then shown i wan't to display some message from another channel, but the result is nothing... I do have result when i use the same code on the page where all the postst are.

Can one place a 'entries tag' on a page which is generated by a {title_permalink=''}??

Answer (score 4):

When displaying channel:entries on a page where the url does not determine that particular conent, for example a sidebar list of recent entries you need to add the **dynamic="no"** parameter to your channel entries tag.

Comment: That's was the problem i didn't had the dynamic="" parameter in my Channel Entries tag! Thank you!

Comment: @user3191 Make sure you mark your question as answered :D

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how you link to the page, it matters what the current page's URL is.

Yes, you should be able to use a basic Channel Entries tag with a couple of important parameters. Note: Do not put one Channel Entries tag inside of another.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" dynamic="no" limit="5"}
  {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```